# Split Column in PowerBi

Tags: database, split, powerbi, powerquery

I have been stuck in splitting column in PowerBi.
The below picture is the example of the data I would need to split.

[image]

In the qualification tab, I would want to seperate those details along with the dates to separate columns.

Do you think you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice at first that all the data is in a single row

So...

Right click the Qualifications column, split column ... by delimiter... [x] --Custom--, and for the custom choose a line feed (by clicking in that box and using insert special character for line feed at the bottom of the box), for advanced options pick [x]rows

[image]

That gets you this, on different rows

[image]

Right click the qualifications column, split column .. by delimiter .. select or enter delimiter: choose --custom-- and enter **space**(

Note: In step above I mean to actually use two characters - a space followed by a parenthesis

[image]

Right click the new column, Replace Values, and replace **)** with nothing

[image]

Click select that column and transform ... data type .. date

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Qualifications", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#(lf)", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Qualifications"),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Qualifications", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Qualifications", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" ("}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Qualifications.1", "Qualifications.2"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Qualifications.1", type text}, {"Qualifications.2", type text}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type1",")","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Qualifications.2"}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"Qualifications.2", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type2"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what you want for a result.  In particular you don't show if you want to retain the surrounding parentheses.

If you do want to retain them, then merely split on the transition by inserting this M-Code in the Advanced Editor in the place where you want to do the split.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Qualifications", type text}}),

//split on transition from " " to "("
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Qualifications", 
      Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => c <> "(", {"("}), {"Qualifications", "Date"}),

//remove trailing " " from first column
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{{"Qualifications", Text.Trim, type text}})
in
    #"Trimmed Text"
```

[image]

If you want to remove the parentheses, then just split on the `"("` and remove the trailing `")"`